# User Filter Options on Archive Page

Tags: custom-field, loop, filters

I have looked into many of the questions here on the subject but none seem to fit my requirements.

I have an Event website. 
Each Post (Event) has custom fields:
    -Date
    -City
    -Venue

I load the archive based on the custom fields Date. 
Let's say we have 20 results,  what I need is a filter (dropdown) above the results which contains the custom field (City) of the posts.

The idea is that the dropdown list contains only the cities which are used in the 20 results.

I am using the standard archive.php and not custom posts.

Any pointers to other answers which fit would be appreciated.

Thanks

Below is the code I use to list all the events by custom field date.

```
    $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );  
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array('posts_per_page' => '25',
   'post_status'=>'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
           array(
              'key' => 'eventdate',
              'value' => $today,
              'compare' => '>=',
               'type' => 'DATE'
            )),
'meta_key' => 'eventdate',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'));
$wp_query->query($args); 

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you using ACF or the WP core custom fields?

Comment: ACF Custom fields